# Unable to run node commands with new user

Tags: command-line, nodejs

I have two users: one old and another new. Both, my old user and my new user, can run node. But suddenly, with my new user, whenever I enter any command related to node I receive the same error copied below.

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:79
      let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
      ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

Please help me guys. And yes, node commands are still working on my old user.

Comment: With what method did you install node.js?

Answer (score 0):

*node* is the name of the Node.js snap package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. For example, to check your node version type:

```
$ node -v
```

To get rid of the error message in your question login as your new user and run the following command to enable npm update checking:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/your-username/.config
```

Replace  **`your-username`** in the above command with your own username.